# How to create a signature using crypto class

Tags: crypto

> The method signature must be generated by taking the query string, and creating a HMAC-SHA256 signature using your API key as the secret key.

salesforce way of generating  signature

```
String algorithmName = 'RSA';
String key = '';
Blob privateKey = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(key);
Blob input = Blob.valueOf('12345qwerty');
Crypto.sign(algorithmName, input, privateKey);
```

its not working. I am not able to get the meaning of first line,
I have referred this links
http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/07/06/using-rsa-sha1-with-salesforce-crypto-class/
[enter link description here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008wRSIAY)

what should be proper value of input :: any random value OR some meaningful value

Answer (score 5):

The input for `String key` should be the PKCS#8 formatted Private key. If you follow the instructions on the blog you linked to, use the string of characters between the outputted `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`.

Short Version of instructions -

1. Generate a private / public key pair (CA or Self signed is up to you), formatted RSA / SHA1, in .PEM format.
2. Convert .pem format private key to PKCS#8 format `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in myPrivateKey.pem -outform PEM`
3. Take terminal output between `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END PRIVATE KEY-----` and use as `String key = '';` - Make sure you do not have any line-breaks or carriage returns in the string, as is usually output to the terminal. This will make your key not work as Apex does not support multi-line strings.

Answer (score 0):

I am a NodeJS developer and am confronted with the same confusing problem.
Just as the comment above said, the PKCS8 salesforce wants is a little bit different from what can be generated by Node's native `crypto` module.

```
privateKey
  .replace(/-{5}(BEGIN|END) PRIVATE KEY-{5}/g, '')
  .replace(/\n/g, ''),
```

After wasting a whole day, with the help of this blog I finally managed to figure out this trick in my LWC javascript.

In my JS case, I also had to output the signature-blob as base64 in apex due to `not a valid utf-8 string` error, which shows up if u use `Blob.toString()`